# How to store CTRL-A (0x01) in a C++ string?

Tags: c++, string, character-encoding, escaping

I want to store <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (0x01) in a C++ string. Tried the following, but it does not work. Could you tell what I am missing here?

```
string s = "\u0001";
```

I get the error when compiled in g++:

```
error: \u0001 is not a valid universal character
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you get is due to 2.2/2 in C++03:

> If the hexadecimal value for a universal character name **is less than
>   0x20** or in the range 0x7F-0x9F (inclusive), or if the universal
>   character name designates a character in the basic source character
>   set, then the program is ill-formed.

So, for a string literal you have to use `\x1` or `\1` instead (and you can add leading zeroes to taste). Alternatively if you do only want one character in your string:

```
string s;
s.push_back(1);
```

or:

```
string s(1,1);
```

The restriction is relaxed in C++11 (2.3/2):

> if the hexadecimal value for a universal-character-name **outside the
>   c-char-sequence, s-char-sequence, or r-char-sequence of a character or
>   string literal** corresponds to a control character (in either of the
>   ranges 0x00–0x1F or 0x7F–0x9F, both inclusive) or to a character in
>   the basic source character set, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 5):

Since you already have your value in hexadecimal it's very simple:

```
std::string s = "\x01";
```

This works for any hexadecimal char literal. The general format is `\x<hex number>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
std::string s = "\001";
```

Note that the code is octal.

Answer (score 2):

A `string` stores ASCII characters; the compiler needs to translate from the input character set to ASCII. This mapping is *implementation defined*; it appears your compiler vendor has decided not to map from U+0001 to ASCII 0x01.

You should be able to initialize the string using

```
string s = "\001";
```

Comment: A `std::string` stores `char`, which may or may not have anything to do with ASCII.